# c# - how to go through ms access db and get list of tables?

Tags: c#

Im copying data from a ms access db to sql server like this...

```
string sSQLTable = table;
string myExcelDataQuery = "Select * from " + sSQLTable;
string sSqlConnectionString = connStr;
string sClearSQL = "DELETE FROM " + sSQLTable;
SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(sSqlConnectionString);
SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sClearSQL, SqlConn);
SqlConn.Open();
SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlConn.Close();
OleDbConnection OleDbConn = new OleDbConnection(String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}", fileName));
OleDbCommand OleDbCmd = new OleDbCommand(myExcelDataQuery, OleDbConn);
OleDbConn.Open();
OleDbDataReader dr = OleDbCmd.ExecuteReader();
SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sSqlConnectionString);
bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = sSQLTable;
while (dr.Read())
{
    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
}
OleDbConn.Close();
```

But this only does it for one table name...how do i put this in a loop and get each table name and call this function to copy data for each table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following article](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/10/01/GetListOfTablesInMicrosoftAccessUsingGetSchema.aspx) which illustrates how to retrieve a list of available tables by querying the schema.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some reference. Note: I have tested it. You can follow and try.

[Get List of Tables in an Access Database - ADO.NET Tutorials](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/10/01/GetListOfTablesInMicrosoftAccessUsingGetSchema.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can run below query but need to have Administrative priviledge.

SELECT Name
FROM MSysObjects
WHERE
Left([Name],1)<>"~"
AND
Left([Name],4)<>"MSys"
AND
Type In (1,4,6)
ORDER BY Name